# Anomaly in CoW (Copy on Write) of Swift Array with Reference type items

Tags: arrays, swift, copy-on-write

**My understanding:**

Arrays in Swift are value types. Arrays and other collections in Swift has CoW (Copy on Write) mechanism so when an array is passed as an argument to a function or simply assigned to another variable, Swift will not actually create another copy of array rather simply passes the reference to same array. On attempting to write/modify the array, swift will create a new copy of Array (Assuming that original array reference is still strongly held) and write operation will be performed on new copy of the array.

**Background:**

In this problem, I am trying to store class instances (reference types in Array)

```
class TestClass {
    var name: String = "abcd"
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

I am creating a local variable a (array) of `TestClass` and passing it as an argument to `someFunc`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var a = [TestClass(name: "abcd"), TestClass(name: "efgh"), TestClass(name: "ijkl")]
    debugPrint(UnsafePointer(&a))
    self.someFunc(array: a)
}
```

In `someFunc` I assign the argument to another variable `anotherArray` and perform `append` operation on `anotherArray`. As Expected CoW of Array kicks in and creates a new copy of Array so memory addresses of `array` and `anotherArray` are different.

```
func someFunc(array: [TestClass]) {
    var anotherArray = array
    anotherArray.append(TestClass(name: "mnop"))

    debugPrint(UnsafePointer(&array))
    debugPrint(UnsafePointer(&anotherArray))
}
```

[image]

As expected, when a value type is copied, all the inner reference types will also be recreated/copied, to prove that

```
  func someFunc(array: [TestClass]) {
    var anotherArray = array
    anotherArray.append(TestClass(name: "mnop"))

    for var value in array {
        debugPrint(UnsafePointer(&value))
    }

    for var value in anotherArray {
        debugPrint(UnsafePointer(&value))
    }
}
```

[image]

Clearly memory addresses of the arrays are different (`array !=== anotherArray`) and also memory addresses of all the items inside `array` and `anotherArray` are also different (`array[i] !=== anotherArray[i]`)

**Issue:**

```
    func someFunc(array: [TestClass]) {
        var anotherArray = array
        anotherArray.append(TestClass(name: "mnop"))
        anotherArray[0].name = "Sandeep"
        debugPrint(array[0].name)
    }
```

With the clear understanding that array and anotherArray are two different copies and also reference types inside each array are completely different, one would expect if I change the value of `anotherArray[0].name` to "Sandeep", `array[0].name` should still be "abcd" but it returns "Sandeep"

[image]

Why is that? Am I missing something here? Has it got anything to do with Array's Special Accessor `mutableAddressWithPinnedNativeOwner` ?

**Array's Special Accessor `mutableAddressWithPinnedNativeOwner`**

If I understand it correctly, rather than simply pulling out the value at specific index, copying it, modifying it and replacing the original value like in case of *Dictionary*, `mutableAddressWithPinnedNativeOwner` simply access the physical memory of the value at specific index and modifies it. 
But that shouldn't make a difference when entire array itself is modified :| Am confused here

**Complete running code:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var a = [TestClass(name: "abcd"), TestClass(name: "efgh"), TestClass(name: "ijkl")]
        debugPrint(UnsafePointer(&a))
        self.someFunc(array: a)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }

    func someFunc(array: [TestClass]) {
        var anotherArray = array
        anotherArray.append(TestClass(name: "mnop"))

        for var value in array {
            debugPrint(UnsafePointer(&value))
        }

        for var value in anotherArray {
            debugPrint(UnsafePointer(&value))
        }

        anotherArray[0].name = "Sandeep"
        debugPrint(array[0].name)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the real code? The addresses of both arrays are indeed different but the addresses inside the arrays are always the same respectively.

Comment: @vadian: Yes it is the real code. Address of the arrays are different also if you look at address of items of array and another array they are `0x00007ffee4efce38` and `0x00007ffee4efce40` respectively

Comment: @vadian: Posted the complete code in the latest update

Comment: In the second screenshot I see 3 identical addresses ending with `0df8` and 4 with `0e00`

Comment: @vadian: Thats what confused me also :) If you see in array there were 3 elements, for all the three elements address were same, I thought might be some optimisation in swift so I intentionally set different names for each instance hoping that address will be different but they were same :| last 4 are after appending the element to array so now it shows same address for all 4 elements :|

Comment: using Xcode 11.3.1 and swift version Swift5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `UnsafePointer(&value)` returns the wrong value (maybe it is the head of the array or something like this). I changed the `someFunc` a little bit.

```
func someFunc(array: [TestClass]) {
    var anotherArray = array
    anotherArray.append(TestClass(name: "mnop"))

    for var value in array {
        debugPrint(Unmanaged.passUnretained(value).toOpaque())
    }

    for var value in anotherArray {
        debugPrint(Unmanaged.passUnretained(value).toOpaque())
    }

    anotherArray[0].name = "Sandeep"
    debugPrint(array[0].name)
}
```

And the output is the following:

```
0x0000600003f29360
0x0000600003f29380
0x0000600003f29400

0x0000600003f29360
0x0000600003f29380
0x0000600003f29400
0x0000600003f29340
```

As you can see, both arrays contain the same objects, and this is the expected behavior. Array stores references to `TestClass` objects (not values) and copies these references during CoW, but the objects remain the same.

Comment: Amazing:) That means when a value type is copied its reference types are only shallow copied (pointing to same instance) and not recreated (deep copy) is it? Is this behaviour of shallow copying reference types is limited to array or its applicable to all value types?

Comment: It is applicable for all values. The thing is that the system can't create the copy of the reference type object because there is no default implementation of the `copy` method for such objects. And it is obviously why this is so. If several reference type objects create a retain cycle, then we will have an infinite loop if the system tries to create a copy of any of these objects.